# Make USB bootable for kali linux

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, usb-creator

I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS. I want to make a bootable usb stick using kali iso image file for Kali Linux installation. I tried following ways:

1. `unetbootin-linux-608` - it is just writing 4 text files and then asking for reboot without writing files.
2. I also tried http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install. It created the live usb with 3.2GB data, but when i am rebooting by selecting pen drive as boot device, it is not loading rather Ubuntu is booting up.
3. Startup Disk Creator - but giving same problem as [mentioned here](/questions/162760/startup-disk-creator-uncaught-exception-error)

Can anybody please suggest me proper way/tool to create bootable pen drive.

Comment: Did you check md5 checksum of the kali iso file ?

Comment: I installed Kali 1 month back, that time i verified that and successfully installed also, so does it requires now again and every time i install the same image?, i think image is fine

Comment: Yeh, if it's the same image, it's fine, can you try another usb stick ?

Comment: forgot to mention that i used the same pen drive that time also, that time i used PowerISO software of window 7. So pen drive is also fine, can u tell any way

Comment: @DavidFoerster if the 2 question have some common words it doesn't make it a duplicate. Please judge the question after properly reading it

Comment: @NarendraJaggi: Fair enough. I retracted my vote to close.

Comment: I used to use Windows software such as unetbootin but I found I always had mixed results. But using `dd` approach, such as following Kali's `dd` instructions that you already linked, consistently works for me, for Kali 1.0.9 and Kali 2.0. Since you said you are able to get into Ubuntu, could plug the usb stick in, and copy the results of these commands, and update the question to include this info: Run `uname -a`. Run `sudo fdisk -l`. Finally, run the `sudo dd` command as instructed on Kali's website, but be sure to copy what command you are using, as well as the stats it gives you when done.

Comment: Did you check the .iso file in virtual box or vm-ware make sure its not corrupted try using g-parted format the usb device and add flag 'boot' to it and apply changes then extract the .iso file and copy it to the usb device and try booting

Comment: @ArUn i was able to create the bootable with same iso file with USB  image disk writer so there was no issue with iso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,Installed Kali!! Using **Ubuntu's Disk Image Writer!!**

Comment: What is the actual name for apt-get install, or name to call if installed, or how do you access it? I am stuck trying to make a bootable Kali Linux USB now, and cannot.

Comment: nevermind... `unetbootin` works great!!!

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems as you with Unetbootin. Give it a try with the `dd` utility instead.

First make sure that the usb-drive is **not mounted**.

Get the usb device name with:

```
lsblk
```

And then use the `dd` command like this to create the bootable usb:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/your.iso of=/dev/xxx && sync
```

Replace `/dev/xxx` with your usb device name. (Do **NOT**  append a partition number, for example like this /dev/sdb1).

Comment: i mentioned the second approach, with dd atleast data was written but on bootup it didn't worked.

Comment: same here.. did anybody successfully boot this?

Comment: I am trying to Triple boot Kali Linux with windows and Ubuntu. Ubuntu and Kali Linux are both already installed on my Dell-Inspiron. I was following the tutorial at this page to make the Bootable Kali USB Drive. I was able to create it on both windows as well as Ubuntu, but when I go to the boot menu and try to boot from the USB, nothing happens and I get the usual page where I have to select which OS to boot into. Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: able to write the data using `dd if=kali-linux-light-2016.1-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M && sync` but still not able to boot from USB

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257439/unable-to-create-kali-linux-bootable-usb-with-windows10-ubuntu